# Checking Visible Divs not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var len = $(".per:visible").length;

$("#add-person").click(function(){
    if ($(".persons div:visible").next().is(':hidden')){

        $(".persons div:visible").next().slideDown('slow' , function(){
                console.log(len);
                if ( $(".persons div:hidden").length == 10){
                    $("#add-person").hide(); //Hide button once visible divs equal 10.
                }
            });
    }
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="persons">
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
    <div class="per"> <!-- Contains other divs and other HTML --> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.per{
     display:none;
}

.per:first-child { display:block; }
```

When I click the button that triggers the above function I expect to see the number of visible divs with the class of `.per` but it always returns 0.

Do I mis-understand something? From what I read on SO this is the way I check for visible divs. What is wrong?

Comment: When is `$(".per:visible").length` executed? It sounds like it is executed when there are `0` visible elements. The variable `len` won't dynamically update when the number of visible elements changes, it will remain the same as when it was executed. That's because `$(".per:visible")` is cached (i.e., it isn't queried each time). It sounds like you need to make that query *inside* of the event listener in order to make that check each time the event is triggered.

Comment: I think your issue has been solved by adding additional CSS rule for displaying block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would solve your issue of visible and invisible divs.

```
var visible=0, invisible=0;
$('.per').each(function(){
if($(this).is(':visible'))
{
    visible++;
}
else
{
    invisible++;
}
})
```

Here is the working fiddle of your question

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m77xwdvk/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all of your div.per elements are hidden by default. Try to add this CSS below your css file

```css
.per:first-child { display:block; }
```

and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You already hide all the divs by using `display:none` in `.per`

Try to set atleast one `div` `visible`.